# Arrange the data frame activity - next activity based on time

Tags: r

I have a data frame like this

```
node <- c("ABC_Amod_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Amod_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1","ABC_Arvali_wdm-1/1/10/1")
activity <- c("LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","LOSS_OF_SIGNAL-OTS","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","LOSS_OF_MULTIPLEX_SECTION-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A","UNDERLYING_RESOURCE_UNAVAILABLE-OMS_A")
time <- c("2020-05-09 04:50:42","2020-05-09 06:16:54","2020-05-09 09:30:49","2020-05-09 13:33:20","2020-05-10 20:01:10","2020-05-10 20:01:11","2020-05-10 20:35:24","2020-05-11 16:33:31","2020-05-16 13:40:29","2020-05-16 14:39:00","2020-05-16 15:12:52","2020-05-18 17:12:57")

df <- data.frame(node, activity, time)
df
```

I have try this code

```
library(dplyr)

x<-df %>%
  arrange(node, activity) %>%
  group_by(node) %>%
  mutate(nextactivity = lead(activity)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  dplyr::select(-time) %>%
  na.omit()
```

but this one not give me a desired output. it still remain n nodes I need n-1 nodes.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? When I try my answer on your new data it seems to work. Can you show what output you are getting and what output you would expect?

Comment: yes it is working on R. but not on R cloud. expected output is when we run this code on R output

Comment: Did you assign the result back to the object? `df <- df %>% arrange(node, time) %>%
  group_by(node)......`

Comment: Yes. but output is same

Comment: Maybe this is R-cloud specific issue then. It works for me as expected in RStudio. I hope you have used `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::mutate` in the code everywhere.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much for spending time for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep `time` in numeric format, `arrange` the data and remove `NA` rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  arrange(node, time) %>%
  group_by(node) %>%
  mutate(nextactivity = lead(activity)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  dplyr::select(-time) %>%
  na.omit()

# node  activity nextactivity
#  <chr> <chr>    <chr>       
#1 A     cdf      abc         
#2 A     abc      nop         
#3 A     nop      ghi         
#4 A     ghi      jkm         
#5 B     tuv      pqr
```

Comment: when I run this code for original data set, it still did not group. so do you have any suggestion about group_by(node) part

Comment: You might have `plyr` loaded. Try using functions with package names. `dplyr::group_by` and `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: It still not working.  I have add it question comment part

Comment: Does this work on the sample data that you have provided in your question?

Comment: No I have edit my question. by my original data set. can you check it.